# Sudoku PHP Guardar Valores

Tags: php

estoy intentando hacer un pequeño sudoku en php, y mi pregunta seria la siguiente, me gustaria poder guardar los valores que introduce el usuario y poder recargarlos cuando haga enviar, alguien sabe?

```
<?php
echo "<form action='sudoku.php' method='POST'>";
    echo "<table>";
    if (isset($_POST['Sudo[][]'])) {
        $array1 = $_POST['Sudo[][]'];
    } else {
        $array1 = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4],
        [8,9,4,2,3,7,5,6,1],
        ['','','','','','','','',''],
        ['','','','','','','','',''],
        ['','','','','','','','',''],
        ['','','','','','','','',''],
        ['','','','','','','','',''],
        ['','','','','','','','',''],
        ['','','','','','','','','']];
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++) {
        echo "<tr>";
        for ($j = 0; $j < 9; $j++) {

        echo "<td><input name='Sudo[$i][$j]' type='number' max=9 min=1 style='width:30px' value='".$array1[$i][$j]."'></input></td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    echo "<input type='submit'><br />";
echo "</form>";
echo var_dump($_POST['Sudo']);
?>
```

Comment: Puedes guardar los datos de ese array en una variable de sesion

Comment: Una forma de hacerlo es haciendo una conexion con la base de datos y guardar los datos en una tabla, luego vuelves a consultarla para construir el sudoku con los datos y enviarlo